# Unable to integrate Artifactory with jenkins using jenkins configuration settings

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

While integrating Artifactory with Jenkins, using the configuration settings, I am getting the following error

> JFrog Artifactory not found at http:<My_URL>:8082/artifactory/artifactory

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: [Hiw to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems extra context is getting added due to incorrect configuration i.e. end URL should be *http:<My_URL>:8082/artifactory/* but not with double Artifactory contexts.

Make sure to specify JFrog Platform URL as ***<My_URL>:8082/*** in the Jenkins configurations i.e. without any artifactory context (/artifactory).